# In "Please find attached invoice number A123", what is the part of speech of "number A123"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

The title says it all. Thanks in advance for any information!

Answer (score -1):

I would say it is an adjective (describes a noun - in this case the invoice).

Take a look at https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/parts-of-speech-table.htm for a very handy table of the different parts of speech.

Comment: But is there any reference on using a noun as a post-modifier?

Comment: @KentTong [This link](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/postmodifier) includes an example of a postmodifier including the noun **corner**, so a postmodifier including the noun **number** must be fine. Also the postmodifier **number A123** can be considered to be short for **with the number A123**. After all you find an _invoice_ attached, not an _invoice number_  which is the only other interpretation you can put on the sentence.

Comment: It's an identifying postmodifier.

Comment: How is that which identifies an invoice different from the title of a book or film, please?